# Set path to gcc for native compilation

Tags: microsoft-windows, path, native-comp

Is there a way to tell emacs to use a specific path to GCC for native compilation, overriding any GCC found by searching the PATH environment variable?

I've been trying to set up Emacs 29.1 on Windows using the official builds. When trying to install Magit with package-install I got a lot of error messages about native compilation. I think that emacs had detected that GCC was on my PATH, and tried to native-compile the modules on installation. This failed (but the error message was no help, basically just a stacktrace of hexadecimal addresses).

My installation of GCC was an MSYS2 UCRT64 installation. [This reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/u3nl5v/comment/i4qkxg5/) suggested installing mingw-w64-x86_64-libgccjit in MSYS2 - i.e. a MinGW64 libgccjit (and it's dependencies, which includes GCC itself). Doing so, and then prepending the MinGW64 bin directory to the path in PowerShell before invoking runemacs did indeed fix installation of Magit!

I'm happy to keep the MinGW64 installation of GCC etc. around to keep emacs happy, but I don't want it to be in my PATH - if I'm compiling things on Windows, ucrt is generally the right C runtime to use.

Comment: Maybe try http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/PROBLEMS?id=8e0f134653b2951e80cd5659fba5c36e416931fa#n3356 to point to the version that Emacs wants?

Comment: I don't think LIBRARY_PATH is going to help on Windows. From digging around the source a bit, it seems like the conversion from the symbol gccjit to the filename libgccjit-0.dll is being done with a lookup in dynamic-library-alist, so if I were to put the full path in there, it would work! However putting the change in early-init.el doesn't stop the wrong dll being loaded.